# Solving an equation with a variable to the Xth degree

Tags: r

I have a following equation in R:

```
A<-B*(C+D)^X
```

How can I determine X if I know A, B, C, and D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an algebra problem than a specifically R problem - to solve this problem, it's helpful to learn about logarithms. Here's the definition of a logarithm:

[image]

As you can see, logarithms are helpful for calculating bases and exponents when you have the other two variables in an equation.

In your example, you have `A = B(C+D)^X`

Let simplify that to `A/B = (C+D)^X`

Using the definition above, we find that `X<-log(A/B, C+D)` (note in R log notation is `log(variable, base)`

**NOTE:** This only works C+D>0 and C+D != 1 and A/B > 0